# How to make div height increase to include floated image

Tags: html, css

This is the problem.  I have an div which includes a few paragraphs of text in it and then an image which is floated right.  The image floats right as it should but the containing div does not expand vertically to accommodate for the image.  I know that I can manually set the height of the div but this becomes problematic because I would like to use this same div for each page of my site and thus the heights will need to be different.

Here is a code sample:

```css
#main_contentbox {
  width: 918px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #000;
}

#main_contentbox img#sample {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_contentbox">
  <h1 class="page"> The Event </h1>
  <img id="sample" src="sample.jpg" />
  <p>
    stackoverflow is awesome!stackoverflow is awesome!stackoverflow is awesome!stackoverflow is awesome!stackoverflow is awesome!stackoverflow is awesome!stackoverflow is awesome!</p>

  <p>stackoverflow is awesome!stackoverflow is awesome!stackoverflow is awesome!stackoverflow is awesome!


</div>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can change the behaviour of how parent blocks deal with floated content by changing the `overflow` property. This should do it:

```
#main_contentbox { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: :o how can i have missed that .. +10 (if i could) i always used the clear:both technique ...

Comment: This particular feature of `overflow` isn't *that* well-known.

Comment: What has `overflow` got to do with the box model? Is this another one of CSS crazies? This works though! +1

Comment: i love this but an explanation about why this works would be great.

Comment: This clips the containing image for me. How to make the height the same as the image that's dynamically loaded?

Comment: @billynoah see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

While @cletus's solution is technically correct, setting overflow to *any* value other than `overflow: visible` (the default), `initial` (explicitly use default), or `inherit` with a `visible` parent will result in the element creating a new [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context). A block formatting context is a region in which floating elements can interact with blocks. This situation (floated element inside of a non overflow:visible element) is explicitly listed as the reason for the creation of a new context being a necessity:

> "if a float intersected with the scrolling element it would forcibly rewrap the content. The rewrap would happen after each scroll step, leading to a slow scrolling experience." - [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

As a result, the height will be be recalculated for any immediate children within this new context, and their heights will be included.

I prefer to use `overflow: auto` to accomplish this when I can, but `scroll`, `overlay`, or `hidden` will all produce the desired result of including the float in the calculation of the height of the parent element.

Comment: Thanks for this. @cletus's answer worked, but I had no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

Using an `:after` pseudoclass, you can have the named div automatically append a clear fix.  Add this to your css file:

```
#main_contentbox:after {
  content: "Foo";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  clear: both;
}
```

With that in place, you don't have to do anything to force `main_contentbox` to grow to contain its floats, no matter what page you're on.

Comment: I will have to look into this further, it seems that with CSS there are many many hacks or quick fix ways of doing things as well, but I am concerned with learning the right ways.

Comment: Not sure what qualifies for a "right" way of doing things, but I use float a -lot- at work, and having a couple of these :after pseudoclasses, I never have to think about it when designing.  Add elements with floated classes and the container classes always know to do the right thing.  Clears seem to be a fairly common way to achieve this (I know at least Wikipedia's default skin does this with a dedicated clear class).  My solution is just an extrapolation of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something with JavaScript maybe:

```
window.onload = FixMyDiv();

function FixMyDiv()
{
  var divh = document.getElementById('main_contentbox').style.offsetHeight;
  var imgh = document.getElementById('sample').style.offsetHeight;

  if(divh < imgh + 50) document.getElementById('main_contentbox').style.height = imgh + 50;


}
```

Comment: Not to knock javascript, it definitely has its place, but I was looking for a purely CSS solution because this is problem is strictly design and layout based.