# How to increase the height of the <div> tag as the number of records increases

Tags: c#, css, html

[How to add <span> tag during runtime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327922/how-to-add-span-tag-during-runtime-in-c-sharp)

Please refer the above link.

> Carefully note the  border in the image

The detailed question I have described and I have solved the problem with one of the answers mentioned therein. Now After applying that method the border, which I am referring in that Image will remain same, when the number of Images increases. The body will be increasing but the height of the  remains the same. What is the method I can use to solve this problem. I have also referred this 2 links regarding the same question but even those are not working.

[Enlarge div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838128/enlarge-div-tag)

[How to dynamically increase the Height of Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504246/how-to-dynamically-increase-the-height-of-a-div-based-on-the-contents)

and if I remove the modification I made in codebehind the div will automatically increase. so  I guess the problem is with the modifications I have done.

Comment: Could you show us an snippet of your code?

Comment: @maqjav.. Its there in the Link which I have shared at the beginning of the question.. Please refer it..

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was a link to another similar problem. I'm going to check it out :)

Comment: If you are too lazy to post your code here, better not expecting an answer for you.

Comment: @maqjav.. Yea sure... :)

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal.. That shows even you are too lazy to jus click a link.. Wel I don't expect answer from such guys too.. You carry on your work.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search I got the solution for this problem..

You just need to add `overflow:hidden` in the style property of .

Got the answer from the below link.
[how to make div height increase to include floated image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159843/how-to-make-div-height-increase-to-include-floated-image?rq=1)

It works as expected now. :)